# Eclipse pluginCustomization

Tags: eclipse

I would like to add default ssh connections to eclipse as global configuration (generic through workspaces). For that, im using -pluginCustomization runtime parameter. Here is my test.ini file:

```
org.eclipse.remote.core/connectionTypeId=org.eclipse.remote.JSch
org.eclipse.remote.core/connections/org.eclipse.remote.JSch/m3ulcb/JSCH_ADDRESS_ATTR=localhost
org.eclipse.remote.core/connections/org.eclipse.remote.JSch/m3ulcb/JSCH_IS_PASSWORD_ATTR=true
org.eclipse.remote.core/connections/org.eclipse.remote.JSch/m3ulcb/JSCH_LOGIN_SHELL_COMMAND_ATTR=/bin/bash -l -c '{0}'
org.eclipse.remote.core/connections/org.eclipse.remote.JSch/m3ulcb/JSCH_PORT_ATTR=22
org.eclipse.remote.core/connections/org.eclipse.remote.JSch/m3ulcb/JSCH_TIMEOUT_ATTR=0
org.eclipse.remote.core/connections/org.eclipse.remote.JSch/m3ulcb/JSCH_USERNAME_ATTR=foo
org.eclipse.remote.core/connections/org.eclipse.remote.JSch/m3ulcb/JSCH_USE_LOGIN_SHELL_ATTR=true
eclipse.preferences.version=1
```

I see that the connectionTypeId takes efect and my default connection goes to ssh. The rest just does not work.
Any help would be really appreciate.

Thanks!

PS: I'm an eclipse newbie